# Creating new node based on detection of child node

Tags: xslt

The feedback from my previous post worked a charm but I have encountered the following with some of the documents on our system. The output is as below.

```
<par def='1'>
   <run>This is start of line one para one </run>
   <run>text hotspot 1</run>
   <run> remainder of line one<break/></run>

   <run>This is line 2 </run>
   <run>another hotspot </run>
   <run>remainder of line 2 <break/></run>
 </par>
```

Is it possible to generate the following output using XSLT?

```
<document>
   <para>This is start of line one para one text hotspot 1 remainder of line one</para>

   <para>This is line 2 another hotspot remainder of line 2</para>
</document>
```

ie, the `<break/>` node indicates the end of a sentence but a sentence may run over several `<run>` nodes.

In case anyone is wondering, the source data is generated from Lotus Notes in it's DXL schema format.

I have been using a 3rd party tool to generate my XSLT to date, I'm happy to provide the code but it's not very clean.

Thank you again in advance, becoming a huge fan of this forum.

Dono

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  In 2.0 it's very easy, using `<xsl:for-each-group select="run" group-ending-with="run[break]">`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It only creates new `<para>` elements for the first `<run>` in a `<par>` and if the immediately preceding `<par>` has a `<break>` in it.

```
<xsl:template match="par">
  <xsl:for-each select="run[preceding-sibling::run[1]/break or not(preceding-sibling::run)]">
    <para>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </para>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="run">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="not(break)">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::run[1]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though isn't a preferable method it works your way..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="par">
    <document>
      <para>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </para>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="run">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="break"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="break">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#60;/para&#62;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#60;para&#62;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should only consider `disable-output-escaping` as an absolute last resort when there's no other way to achieve what you're after.  It's not supported by all processors, and won't work if you're using an API to produce output as a DOM tree in memory rather than a file on disk, for example.

Comment: @IanRoberts, I tried an alternative to the existing one! Since existing answer had it at its best I tried a robust way .. which is ofcourse not preferred .. And not advised :)

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPreceding" match="run"
      use="generate-id((following::break|descendant::break)[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="par">
     <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="run/break"/>
     </document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="break">
  <para><xsl:apply-templates select="key('kPreceding', generate-id())/text()"/></para>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<par def='1'>
    <run>This is start of line one para one </run>
    <run>text hotspot 1</run>
    <run> remainder of line one<break/></run>

    <run>This is line 2 </run>
    <run>another hotspot </run>
    <run>remainder of line 2<break/></run>
</par>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<document>
   <para>This is start of line one para one text hotspot 1 remainder of line one</para>
   <para>This is line 2 another hotspot remainder of line 2</para>
</document>
```

**Explanation**:

This is a typical XSLT 1.0 positional grouping solution. We use a key to express the relationship between a `break` element and all the `run` elements which it identifies as a group.